# How to obtain the ESR For Wordpress

Tags: installation

I signed up for the CiviCRM ESR Program and paid the $20.00, and was given access to the Extended Security Release Group on lab.civicrm.org.  I am showing the latest ESR version is 5.63-ESR.  How do I download the full installation package for Wordpress of the 5.63-ESR?  The Readme.MD file says I need to download the full install at https://civicrm.org/download; so what is the lab.civicrm.org for?  I am also not seeing the ESR offered on https://civicrm.org/download.  Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go into the core folder then near the top right it will say something like "38 releases". Click that. Then you'll see downloads for all the cmses.

Direct link: https://lab.civicrm.org/esr/core/-/releases

Comment: Thank you, Demerit; your help is appreciated.